# maximization using Lagrange

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am maximizing

$f(x,y)=-x$

given the constraint

$g(x,y)=x^2-y^2=0$

To satisfy the non degenerate constraint qualification
I have:

$Dg(x,y)= [2x\quad-2y]$

and the set of $(x,y)$ that satisfy it is having $x=y$.

However on setting up the Lagrange multiplier:

$L(x,y,\lambda)= -x+\lambda(x^2-y^2)$

and getting the first order conditions:

$L_x=-1+ 2\lambda x=0$ and

$L_y=-2\lambda y =0$

$L_\lambda= x^2-y^2=0$

I have a contradiction since for $x=y$

The first equation will give:

$-2 \lambda x= -1$

The second however shows:

$-2 \lambda x=0$

Is there anywhere I have gotten wrong here?

Comment: Is there a constraint on the domain of $x$ and $y$? Otherwise this doesn't make much sense, for then you can take $-x=\pm y$ to be arbitrarily large.

Comment: I guess we can consider x, y to lie in the positive orthant. However, if we do limit to such, intuitively I think the solution is at the origin. However, using the lagrange method, I still arrive at a contradiction? Have some conditions of Constrained optimization been violated? Also in the case of no restriction, can I argue that there is no critical point from the above workings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L_\lambda=x^2+y^2=0$ is missing and you got
$L_x=-1+2x\lambda=0$ and $L_y=2y\lambda=0$
in this case you will get
$-1+2\lambda x=0$ (1)
$-2\lambda y=0$ (2)
$x^2-y^2=0$ (3)
your system has no real solutions

Comment: Hi, sorry I mistype the constraint. The constraints are corrected and the 3 first order conditions are shown now